# Selenium: find element "next to" other element

Tags: java, testing, selenium

I'm adding web tests to my project using Selenium. I already have a bunch of tests that check for a specific element using:

```
final WebElement dateElement = web.findElement(By.id(elementId));
```

And this works fine.
Now I have another requirement. This is in my generated page:

```
<input type="text" id="dateElement" name="dateElement" value="bunch of monkeys" tabindex="101" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">
<span class="error">dateElement is an invalid date</span>
```

How can I get hold of the error message?
I'd like something that allows me to request the span element with class "error" that is just after dateElement.

(This error message was ganerated by Spring MVC, so it's not easy to change it directly. Possible I guess, but I'd prefer not).

Any alternative idea is welcome.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

OK, I already found a solution using Xpath and following-sibling, it wasn't too complicated.

```
final WebElement errorElement = web.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='" + elementId + "']/following-sibling::span[@class='error']"));
```

This gives me what I wanted, and throws a `NoSuchElementException` when it's not here, which is exactly what I want.

Comment: great, I needed the answer also

Comment: This can even be simplified using `final WebElement errorElement = dateElement.findElement(By.xpath("following-sibling::span[@class='error']"));` if you have the actual `WebElement dateElement` available. You have to use that element as the root of the search but notice that the xpath expression should not start with `//` (or `/`) in that case, otherwise it will search from the document root anyway.

Comment: thanks neXus, that is just the method I am looking for!

Answer (score 6):

```
elementSelector = "input + span[class='error']";

final WebElement dateElement = web.findElement(By.cssSelector(elementSelector));
```

Comment: Why not `errorElement` instead of `dateElement`? And what if it's an error unrelated to dateElement?

Comment: @tishma because that was what to OP used