# Java Selenium - Find next element

Tags: java, html, selenium

I have a very similar problem to this one: [Selenium: find element "next to" other element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008588/selenium-find-element-next-to-other-element)

My element looks like this:

```
<div class="a-Trinity has-left-widget has-right-widget" style="cursor: pointer;">
<div class="trinity-left-widget" style="">
    <div>
        <span class="layer-style-rule-slice" style="background-color: rgb(233, 34, 91); border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); margin-top: 12px;"></span>
        <span class="layer-style-rule-slice" style="background-color: rgb(75, 170, 234); border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); margin-top: 6px;"></span>
        <span class="layer-style-rule-slice" style="background-color: rgb(42, 200, 159); border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); margin-top: 0px;"></span>
        <span class="layer-style-rule-slice" style="background-color: rgb(153, 207, 34); border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); margin-top: -6px;"></span>
        <span class="layer-style-rule-slice" style="background-color: rgb(247, 151, 29); border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); margin-top: -12px;"></span>
    </div>
</div>  
<div class="gwt-Label trinity-middle-widget form-text">Street Lights</div>  
<div class="trinity-right-widget" style="">
    <div class="small-switch-container layer-right-switch">
        <div class="small-switch switch-active"> 
            <div class="small-switch-button"></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to check whether switch-active is shown or not. I am using the following to find the correct element:

```
    String className = "gwt-Label trinity-middle-widget form-text";
    String htmlElement = "div";
    String textToFind = layerName; // i.e. Street Light

    List<WebElement> elements = Common.findElementsUsingHtmlXpathClass(driver, htmlElement, className);

    Common.myPrint(thisClass + " elements count: " + elements.size());
    for (WebElement element : elements) {
        // select an element
        String text = Common.getAllAttributes(element, driver);
        if (text != null) {
            text = text.trim();
            if (text.contains(textToFind)) {
                // so this is my element
                // here is where I need to get the next one

            }
        }
    }
```

The code for findElementsUsingHtmlXpathClass:

```
public static List<WebElement> findElementsUsingHtmlXpathClass(WebDriver driver, String htmlElement,
        String className) {
    List<WebElement> elements = driver
            .findElements(By.xpath("//" + htmlElement + "[contains(@class, '" + className + "')]"));
    return elements;
}
```

I cannot see how to apply the solution given in the article quoted, as I do not have an element I can just find by ID.

How can I get this next element?

Went with this solution from cruisepandey. I merely changed the name of the method to reflect it's new function:

```
    public static List<WebElement> findElementsFollowingHtmlXpathClass(WebDriver driver, String htmlElement,
        String className) {
    List<WebElement> elements = driver
            .findElements(By.xpath("//" + htmlElement + "[contains(@class, '" + className + "')]/following-sibling::div[@class='trinity-right-widget']/descendant::div[contains(@class,'switch-active')]"));

    return elements;
}
```

Comment: try this String cssSelector = "gwt-Label.trinity-middle-widget.form-text";

Comment: @cruisepandey - I think you have misunderstood the question. I already have that element!

Comment: Do you actually want to find if the next element contains the class switch-active?

Comment: I think the two answers below contain enough for you to solve this.

Comment: this question does not deserver a down vote without explaining comment . I’m up voting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this :

```
public static List<WebElement> findElementsUsingHtmlXpathClass(WebDriver driver, String htmlElement,
        String className) {
    List<WebElement> elements = driver
            .findElements(By.xpath("//" + htmlElement + "[contains(@class, '" + className + "')]/following-sibling::div[@class='trinity-right-widget']/descendant::div[contains(@class,'switch-active')]"));
    return elements;
}
```

Comment: that does not check the innerHtml - which must contain the text Street Lights.

Comment: actually, that one worked when I called it in place of the original Common.findElementsUsingHtmlXpathClass. Took me a moment to work out how!